# Implicit intent issue in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

In my android application i am using `implicit intent` for turn on the `location service`. I want to restart the application after turn on the `service`. How can i check the result of `location service` and restart my `app`.

I am used following code

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Splash.this);
dialog.setMessage("Location not enabled");
dialog.setPositiveButton("open settings",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface,int paramInt) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(
                android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
dialog.setNegativeButton("cancel",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
        }
    });
dialog.show();
```

I want  to restart my `activity` when i press `back button` from `location service` using below code.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(
    android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Thanks.

Comment: There is no  issues in logcat.I want to load MainActivity after turn on location service from Splash screen. But it stay on splash activity while press back button from location service page.Then i close the app and open again,now it goes to MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Use `startActivityForResult`,

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) 
 {
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS), 1);
 }
```

And check to confirm it in `onActivityResult`,

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode==RESULT_OK)
    {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
        {
            Button bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.turnGPS);
            bt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            this.finish();
        }
        else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No GPS device or service enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG+Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Note: I Assume that your *SplashScreen*'s `launchMode` is not `singleTask`.